# Why does List(Of String).indexof(function) not work?

Tags: vb.net, lambda

I like Lambdas a lot, but I do have trouble with this expression:

```
Dim Test as New List/of String)
Test.add("A")
Test.add("B")

Dim Adress=Test.Indexof(Function (adr) (Trim(Ucase(Adr)) LIke "A")
```

The compiler warns that Stirng is no delegate and will not compile - any Ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List.IndexOf` takes a `T` and returns the index of that object. So you cannot pass a predicate here. I assume you want the first index of a address that  equals-ignore-case "A". Then you can use Linq:

```
Dim matches = Test.Select(Function(Address, Index) New With {Address, Index}).
                   Where(Function(x) x.Address.ToUpper = "A")
If matches.Any() Then
    Dim firstMatch = matches.First()
    Dim firstMatchIndex As Int32 = firstMatch.Index '  0 
    Dim firstMatchAddress As String = firstMatch.Address ' "A"
End If
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you - just for understandig a Question:
Why Adress is initialized as a string and and Index as an Integer?

Comment: @ChristianSauer: Because your generic list contains string, the type of the first argument is string, the second argument(if you use this overload of [`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) or `Enumerable.Where`) is always the index of the item in the sequence. Note that you can get the index only with LINQ's method syntax and not in a query.

Answer (score 0):

The [List(of string).IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx) method takes a string as an input.

The function `Function (adr) Trim(UCase(adr)) LIKE "A"` is a delegate, not a string, so you cannot use it with the IndexOf method.

If you want to perform a search ignoring case, then the following LINQ query will probably work fine for you.

```
Test.First(Function (adr) adr.Equals("A", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```